# shtab tab-completion not working after following instructions

Tags: python, autocomplete, shtab

I tried adding autocomplete using [shtab](https://github.com/iterative/shtab) but it doesn't work :(

The completion file (/etc/bash_completion.d/shtab) looks ok, but hitting **TAB** does nothing

Reproduce:

1. `virtualenv -p python3.6 venv && . venv/bin/activate`
2. `pip install -U shtab`
3. `shtab --shell=bash shtab.main.get_main_parser --error-unimportable | sudo tee /etc/bash_completion.d/shtab`

I changed the `"$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR"/shtab` into `/etc/bash_completion.d/shtab` because [it is not relevant anymore](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/commit/c41a76237bc9dcbfa326eeddd026b66d7646d91d) (*though I did also run the original command*)

My environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python3.6
- shtab==1.5.2
- Bash 4.4.20

---

Tried also on:

1. zsh==5.4.2
2. Docker (`docker run -it python /bin/bash`)

Is there an issue with my environment?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are trying to complete something where there is nothing to complete. For example, `shtab <TAB>` will do nothing since it has no subcommands. The same is true for `cp <TAB>`, `grep <TAB>`, etc.

Meanwhile, `shtab -<TAB>` (and `cp -<TAB>`, `grep -<TAB>`, etc.) will happily complete the supported option flags. This comment may help: [shtab#45@901736610](https://github.com/iterative/shtab/issues/45#issuecomment-901736610).

Comment: Thanks! I added (on the GitHub issue) a complete description of my state and what's exactly still not working on my end